# How to set global request timeout in IIS 7.5?

Tags: iis-7, iis-7.5, timeout, coldfusion, request

We run a Windows Server 2008 VM with IIS 7.5, and on top of that we run Coldfusion 9.

After some server performance issues last week, I saw that backlogged requests in IIS were not timing out.  We got hit with a huge amount of traffic, which slowed down Coldfusion and ultimately slowed down how fast IIS could pass requests to the Coldfusion server.

In Coldfusion, we have a 60-second timeout set globally for requests.  We do have scripts that override this with the `<cfsetting>` tag to get a longer execution time.

After looking in our IIS config file, I see that we only have one site with a request timeout set. I found [this documentation](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/sites/site/limits), but it only outlines how to set this on a per-site basis...

So really, two questions: 1. How can I set a global request timeout for the whole server without adding this setting to each individual site?  2. If I do set this globally, will Coldfusion still be able to have longer running scripts?  (For instance, if I set an IIS timeout to 60 seconds but I use `<cfsetting>` in a Coldfusion script to extend that, would IIS still cut out the script execution at 60 seconds, or will it ignore it's own timeout setting since it passed the script off?)